# Does Ecmascript 6 support a mutable __proto__ property?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In the current Ecmascript 6 draft (November 2012), there is official support for the `__proto__` property (Section B.3.1). This came as a bit of a surprise as, in current browser implementations, the `__proto__` property is deprecated.

If the current draft stands, will ES6 have full support for mutable prototypes? Will I be able to provide a new prototype for an existing object the way I currently can in Firefox?

Comment: The `__proto__` property is "deprecated", because its not a standard property, instead `Object.getPrototypeOf(someObject);` is to be preferred (ECMA5 std, thus X-browser support). Other than that, changing a prototype on-the-fly is not exactly new: I tried it in chrome and IE, changing the prototype of a custom object to `new Array`, without any issues... it's just inherent to the prototype model

Comment: @Elias. Object.getPrototypeOf() is an Ecmascript 5 feature as _ _ proto _ _ was never part of the Ecmascript standard. It appears that _ _ proto _ _ was first deprecated from the Browsers and then introduced (for the first time) in the standard. Although this order of events appear unusual, this appears to be the case. I'm asking specifically about the "new" _ _ proto _ _ in Ecmascript 6 - B.3.1. –

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. It's in the current draft, so yes, it looks like we'll have that. On the other hand, it's still a draft, so anything can change.

Comment: @bfavaretto - The question is if the ES6 _ _ proto _ _ will provide the same mutable behaviour as the older deprecated versions. I.e. is this a complete resurrection of the assumed to be dead _ _ proto _ _ implementation found in some browsers.

Comment: In addition to @benvie's wonderful answer, also note that mutable [[Prototype]] exists in the current draft as `Reflect.setPrototypeOf`. There has been discussion about that being incorrectly placed, and it sounds like `__proto__` will end up being used instead, but it's still a little uncertain at this point.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Currently, it is planned for mutable `__proto__` to be in the spec (and not just in annex b). The current plan is for it to be a magical data property existing solely on Object.prototype and acting as an accessor (the magical part). This property will be deletable as well, removing the ability to mutate `__proto__` for that realm when deleted. I've implemented `__proto__` following this description in my ES6 virtual machine http://benvie.github.com/continuum.

Originally it was to be deprecated and replaced, but no consensus formed on that replacement was. The ability to inherit from builtins is the end goal and the decision was that `__proto__` is already widespread (everything but ie has it) and fulfills this goal, so the path of least resistance was to embrace and codify it.

Comment: just got on that and, whoaw, it's insane!

Comment: This answer seems to be out of date. Looks like the consensus for the replacement (`Reflect.setPrototypeOf`) has formed, and `__proto__` is still in the web legacy Annex B; without plans to move it.

Comment: According to http://webreflection.blogspot.com/2013/05/objectsetprototypeofo-proto-is-in-es6.html, the official way to do this in ES6 will be `Object.setPrototypeOf`

Answer (score 2):

As per Ecmascript 6 released docs, [`__proto__`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-object.prototype.__proto__) still exists but as [Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13839115/does-ecmascript-6-support-a-mutable-proto-property#comment41525657_13841694) and [MattBrowne](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13839115/does-ecmascript-6-support-a-mutable-proto-property#comment47084024_13841694) pointed in the above solution, we can use [`Object.setPrototypeOf`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-object.setprototypeof) which is the modifed version of `__proto__`.

> When the setPrototypeOf function is called with arguments O and proto, the following steps are taken:
>
> - Let O be RequireObjectCoercible(O).
> - ReturnIfAbrupt(O).
> - If Type(proto) is neither Object nor Null, throw a TypeError exception.
> - If Type(O) is not Object, return O.
> - Let status be O.[SetPrototypeOf].
> - ReturnIfAbrupt(status).
> - If status is false, throw a TypeError exception.
> - Return O.