# Object.prototype not working but Object.__proto__ working why?What to do to make my code working in all browsers?

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

I read somewhere that `Object.__proto__` and `Object.prototype` point to the same thing and the `Object.prototype` is the standard way,but last night I was trying to inherit a class with `Object.prototype` but it did not work then I tried to figure out whether both the `Object.__proto__` and `Object.prototype` point to the same thing or not.To my surprise

```
    alert(Object.__proto__===Object.prototype);
```

displayed `false` in an alertbox
So to figure out which one works I wrote the following code

```
    function Cx(){
    this.objName="i m X";
    this.prototype={ };
    this.prototype.getMyName=function (){
alert(this.objName);
       }
    this.__proto__={ };
    this.__proto__.hMyName=function(){
alert("I am hMyName");
      }
    }
    function InheritCx(){
//var y=new Cx();
this.objName="I am InheritCx";
this.__proto__=new Cx();

    }
    y= new InheritCx();
    y.hMyName();//displayes "I am hMyName" in alertbox when using chrome or mozilla
    y.getMyName();//displays an error in chrome and mozilla
```

What's the difference between the two and why doesn't the standard code work?
Furthermore I am interested in knowing what can I do to make prototypal inheritance work in most browsers (IE 6-8,9,10,chrome,firefox,mozilla,opera and webkit)?

Comment: `Object.__proto__ === Function.prototype`, at least in Chrome (also see the comment below)

Comment: *"I read somewhere that `Object.__proto__` and `Object.prototype` point to the same thing..."*. Nope. `Object` is a function, so `Object.__proto__` will be `Function.prototype`.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté cool. What's the version of IE that we need to wait for to die before we can actually use it (serious question)?

Comment: @JanDvorak The leaked Windows Blue's IE (probably IE11) supports `__proto__` I heard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.__proto__` is a *non-standard* way of getting the next object that a given object inherits from. Reading the property is equivalent to the standard `Object.getPrototypeOf()`.

```
var o = {}; // new object

console.log(o.__proto__ === Object.getPrototypeOf(o)); // true
```

---

The `.prototype` property of a function is the object that new objects will inherit from that were created when invoking that function as a constructor *(using `new`)*.

So if we take a function, invoke it as a constructor by using `new`, then take the new object and ask for its `__proto__`, it will be the same object as that found on the `.prototype` property of the constructor.

```
function Ctor() {
    // our constructor function
}

var o = new Ctor();

console.log(o.__proto__ === Ctor.prototype); // true
```

Comment: +1 wasn't aware of `getPrototypeOf`. Though, `__proto__` is becoming standard as of ES6 draft, right?

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: From the last time I looked at the ES6 draft, it was included in an appendex at the end as an optional property for browser environments. So basically seemed to be acknowledging its presence. Not sure where things stand right now.

Comment: I see. This [related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13841694/1331430) says that it should be standardized in ES6, and it is currently in the Annex B (normative) at [B.3.1](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-B.3.1).

Comment: I thought that `var o=new Ctor();` will create an instance of `Ctor` object but you are saying that o inherits from `Ctor`?I wonder what's happening...Is inheritance creating the instance of an object and modifying it?If so what's the difference between prototypal and parasitic inheritance...aren't they both the same?

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: Nice. Hopefully it doesn't get cut.

Comment: @RomanticElectron: `o` inherits from `Ctor.prototype`. The `Ctor` is a function. When we say that `my_object` inherits from `SomeConstructor()`, what we mean is that `my_object` actually inherits from the object located at the `.prototype` property of `SomeConstructor()`. So `new` doesn't make a function or class or anything. It just sets up a relationship between objects.

Comment: @squint finally got you bro

Comment: @FabrícioMatté While I'm against proto (I agree with language creator Branden Eich and Douglas Crockford on this one) and while it is marked as _optional_ , all development versions big browsers (IE11 leaked alphas, Chrome Dev, and Firefox Nightly) seem to support this (Chrome and FF even todaY).

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Is it marked *optional*? I thought everything in the annex B was normative (ES6 draft).

Comment: *"**Annex B (normative) Additional ECMAScript Features for Web Browsers** The ECMAScript language syntax and semantics defined in this annex are required when the ECMAScript host is a web browser. The content of this annex is normative but optional if the ECMAScript host is not a web browser."* Looks like it's not optional for web browsers, but otherwise optional.