# Pushing to a Javascript array that has a __proto__

Tags: javascript, arrays

Ok I am killing my brain here I have an array

```
var myArray = ['Bob', 'Sue', 'Jim'];
myArray.__proto__ = new Entity();

//Entity looks something like this
Entity = function(){
   this.isChanged = false;
   this.add = function(newPerson){
      alert(this.length); //alerts with 3
      alert(JSON.stringify(this)); //alerts a {}
      this.push(newPerson); 
      this.isChanged = true;

  }
}
```

push does not exist on an object but its obviously an array as per the alert returning a 3.

very curious how to access my array that seems to be wrapped by an object thanks to my **proto**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how to access my array that seems to be wrapped by an object thanks to my `__proto__`

It is not wrapped - it just lost it's identity due to your modification of `__proto__`. The array now *inherits* from your `new Entity` instance instead of from `Array.prototype`.

If you want to call `Array` methods on it, you will have to do it using [`.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call):

```
Array.prototype.push.call(this, newPerson);
```

However, your implementation of inheritance is questionable anyway. Even if you use an array object and [mutate its [[prototype]]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23807805/1048572), you rather should be doing

```
var myArray = new Entitiy(['Bob', 'Sue', 'Jim']);

// Entity looks like this
function Entity(arr) {
    if (!Array.isArray(arr)) {
        arr = [];
        // maybe:
        // arr.push.apply(arr, arguments);
    }
    arr.__proto__ = Entity.prototype;
    arr.isChanged = false;
    return arr;
}
Entity.prototype = Object.create(Array.prototype);
Entity.prototype.constructor = Entity;
Entity.prototype.add = function(newPerson) {
    alert(this.length); //alerts with 3
    alert(JSON.stringify(this)); //alerts a ["Bob","Sue","Jim"]
    this.push(newPerson);
    this.isChanged = true;
};
```

Comment: Very Nice! Thank you! this is exactly what I was looking for. If I had posted the full code you would see that I was attempting to use Entity for both objects and arrays. Some of the properties really did not need to be inherited by the array so in an attempt to be more simplistic things got really weird lol.

Answer (score 1):

The array isn't wrapped, it's no longer an array! `__proto__` is a **depricated** getter/setter pair to access an objects internal [[Prototype]]. Since you assign a value the setter is used and you simply overwrite its complete prototype with an instance of `Entity`. That's why `push()` (and all others: pop(), splice(), ... ) doesn't exist any longer.

Why `alert(this.length);`works ? `length` is not a property of Array.prototype but an own property of each Array instance. So it's not overwritten/removed by changing the prototype, your "thing" still has a length. You can check that with following:

```
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(myArray)); // --> ['0', '1', '2', 'length']
```

Of course you can access the properties of your "thing", e.g. `console.log(myArray[1]) // --> 'Sue'`or assign new properties, but you have to use object-methods for it. So if inside `Entity()` instead of `this.push(newPerson)` you use `this[this.length] = newPerson` it will work.

[Reference for `__proto__` here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto).

Comment: The MDN is possibly out of date, \_\_proto\_\_ in some form is being codified into the es 6 spec
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13839115/does-ecmascript-6-support-a-mutable-proto-property

Comment: @JaredSmith: Note that this answer is from 2012, ES6 has moved on. Mutating the [[prototype]] should be done with [`Reflect.setPrototypeOf`](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-reflect.setprototypeof), `__proto__` is still deprecated (but codified - standardised - for web legacy compatibility in [Annex B](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-additional-ecmascript-features-for-web-browsers))

Comment: Thanks guys! I have dropped __proto__ from my toolbag and now using the new version.